# how to change a TextBox text inside a panel from another form that is inside another panel

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, panel

i am working on my first application, i am using VS2017 with c# language.

i am trying hard without success to change a textbox text inside a panel from another form . 
i have a Main_Form that has two panels.
The first panel is my "Main_Panel" which i use to show in it a lot of others forms.
The second panel is my "Info_Panel", it contains a textbox to print the DateTime, and another title_textbox that contains the title of the actual form inside my Main_Panel.
So far, i tried this program inside my Some_Form_load:

```
     private void Some_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
     {
       MainForm f1 = new MainForm();
       f1.Title_Textbox.Text = "Some_Form";
     }
```

But nothing happened, probably because my title_textbox is my "Info_Panel".
I am stuck for hours in this problem, a help would be very appreciate .

Comment: You are changing the `TextBox` of a completely new `MainForm` that you are never showing. You need to either change `f1` to be an already opened `MainForm` or do `f1.ShowDialog();`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, i tried that and it is loading the whole MainForm instead of actualize only the Info_Panel that contains my textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new instance and changing that. You need to change your other one. Here is a rough test of how it should be working.

```
 private void Some_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {
   MainForm f1 = Application.OpenForms.OfType<MainFrm>().FirstOrDefault();
   f1?.Title_Textbox.Text = "Some_Form";
 }
```

This is a quick writeup and is untested, but it should work for what you need.

EDIT: All that this does is grab all MainFrm's in the open applications list, and select the first one. Then it stores that in a variable and you're able to reference that variable to get the form you need :)

Comment: i get an error inside ofType(). i should write "ofType(MainForm) is that it ?